# Looping grep across multiple variables

Tags: r, loops

I'm trying to use grep to identify which observations that match a certain regular expression. But the tricky thing is, the potential matches are distributed a cross multiple columns.

Sample data for reproduction:

```
df <- matrix(nrow = 12, ncol = 20) %>% as.data.frame()
names(df) <- paste0("col", 1:20)
for (i in 1:20){
  df[,i] <- month.name[sample(1:12, 12, replace = T)]
}
df$July.dummy <- 0
```

I've been attempting to loop a `grep` expression over the potential variables to identify matches. In the sample data, the goal is to identify all observations for which "July" appears in any of col1 through col20, and change `df$July.dummy` to 1 accordingly.

```
all.cols <- paste0("col", 1:20)
for (VAR in all.cols){
  df$July.dummy[grep("July", noquote(paste0("df$", VAR)))] <- 1
}
```

This code snippet executes successfully and each of the components seems to "work"... yet none of the observations get changed.

I'm happy to consider other non-loop/non-grep solutions, though I'd also be grateful if someone can show me why my attempted solution doesn't work, for my own enlightenment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dplyr::filter()` can be used with `if_any()` and `if_all()` to apply a filter to more than one column (similar to `across()` for `mutate()`). In the example below, we use `any_of()` to select the columns via the `all.colls` character vector you prepared.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df |> 
  filter(if_any(any_of(all.cols), \(x) str_detect(x, "July")))
#>        col1      col2     col3     col4     col5     col6      col7     col8
#> 1   October       May      May    March    March December      July    March
#> 2   October  November  October    March     July December       May      May
#> 3       May September December   August  October     June   January    April
#> 4     March    August February  January  October February       May    March
#> 5   January  December     July  October    March   August      June  October
#> 6     April     March December February     June February  December December
#> 7  February      July  October     July     June   August September     July
#> 8     March  February  January     June November  January      July February
#> 9     April   October November  January February      May      July December
#> 10 December  February  October November   August    April September  October
#> 11  January     March  January   August     June February     March     July
#>        col9     col10     col11     col12    col13    col14    col15     col16
#> 1     April     March   January       May  January     June November   January
#> 2  November  November  December  December    March     July    April   October
#> 3      June   October     March  February     July  January      May  November
#> 4      June  December       May    August     June     July     June     April
#> 5      July     April  December       May November     July February    August
#> 6   January     March     April  December     July     July      May  November
#> 7   January  February September      July      May     July  October      July
#> 8     March     March      July  December   August November December  December
#> 9      July      June      July September      May   August      May  November
#> 10    March  November      July     April February December February September
#> 11     July September  November  November    March  January    April  February
#>        col17     col18     col19     col20 July.dummy
#> 1    January    August     March  February          0
#> 2   November       May  November   October          0
#> 3   December       May      June  February          0
#> 4      April     March      June     March          0
#> 5    January  February   October      July          0
#> 6       July      July       May     April          0
#> 7  September      July  November September          0
#> 8      April  November   October       May          0
#> 9   December     April  February      July          0
#> 10     March September September   October          0
#> 11       May  February  February   October          0
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using `grep` because you actually need a regular expression to match a pattern, one possibility could be:

```r
df$July.dummy <- apply(df[-length(df)], 1, \(x) as.numeric(any(grep("July", x))))
```

`apply` will apply a function across the rows (`MAR = 1`). The function here is the anyonomous function created with `\(x)` which tests if any element in a row matches the regular expression pattern ("July" here).

Alternatively, you could transpose your data frame and pass it to `grepl` directly:

```r
df$July.dummy <- as.numeric(grepl("July", data.frame(t(df[-length(df)]))))
```

---

However, if you do not need to use a regular expression and just want to do test for equality:

```r
df$July.dummy <- as.numeric(rowSums(df[-length(df)] == "July") > 0)
```

`df[-length(df)] == "July"` creates a logical matrix of `TRUE`/`FALSE` if any element is equal to "July". `rowSums` will then count the number of `TRUE` in each row and then comparing that value to `> 0` will determine if any element in that row matched.

In all instances I used `-length(df)` to exclude the last column, which is `July.dummy`, from any comparison. The `rowSums` expression will be faster if you have a large data set.